# Error 407 when trying to send a request in Java

Tags: java, proxy, request

I have the following code:

```
public class SendRequest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    String url = "http://backoffice.xyz";

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.proxy", 8080, "http");
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setProxy(proxy).build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    //request.addHeader("User-Agent", "USER-AGENT");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    System.out.println("Response Code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
        result.append(line);
    }
        System.out.println(result.toString());

}
```

}

This is returning a 407 Unauthorized Access/Cache Access Denied Error. What code do i need to include so i can authenticate through the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Does your proxy require username/password based authentication? If so, try implementing java.net.Authenticator. I guess you will need to set useSystemProperties

`Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
         PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
              return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
         }
});`

You might need to add `setDefaultCredentialsProvider(CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider)` to the HTTPClientBuilder and use `SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider` instance for that.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i need. Can you please also edit the code i posted with these lines? because, for example, i don;t understand where to insert this setDefault method and credentialsProvider, it's my first proxy authentication for request code:D

Comment: I forgot to mention that upon doing that I will also mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1.Can you check your proxy ?? I'm not sure if `proxy.proxy` is correct.

Your rest of the code seems fine.

2.And also make sure you are updating httpcore version to 4.4 or above. And also you can update httpcore to latest version.

3.You could check the authentication of your proxy as @Goutham mentioned

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Proxy.proxy was there just as an example. what i needed was username/password based authentication